# How to optimize largest value algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have this function that takes an array of numbers, and an array of ranges. The ranges indicate the index in the array of numbers. For each range's sum, I'm supposed to return the largest value. I have a solution, but would like to optimize it to process quicker. Here is my current solution:

```
function maxSum(arr,range){  
  const sums = []
  range.forEach(element => {
    let sum = 0
    for(let i = element[0]; i <= element[1]; i++) {
      sum += arr[i]
    }
    sums.push(sum)
  })
  return Math.max(...sums)
}
```

And here is some sample arguments that would be passed into the function:

```
arr = [1,-2,3,4,-5,-4,3,2,1]
range = [[1,3],[0,4],[6,8]]
```

Any answer that explains how it can be optimized would be appreciated!

Comment: Replacing a `.forEach()` loop with a `for` loop usually speeds things up. (Performance aside, you could make the code "neater" by replacing the `.forEach()` with `const sums = range.map(...)`, and then using `return sum` instead of calling `.push(sum)`.)

Comment: Speaking of optimization you are talking about running time right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use segment tree to calculate the sum for each range, the construction of a segment tree would take O(n*logn) time and each query would take O(logn) time you can find a reference here 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/ 
right now you are looping over the indexes for every range which has a worst case complexity O(n^2) here is a javascript code to implement segment tree

```
function NumArray(nums) {
    var tree = [];
    build(0, nums.length - 1, 0);
    return {sumRange, update};

    function sumRange(left, right) {
        return sumUtil(0, nums.length - 1, 0);

        function sumUtil(currLeft, currRight, treeIdx) {
            if (left > currRight || right < currLeft) return 0;
            if (left <= currLeft && right >= currRight) return tree[treeIdx];

            var mid = currLeft + ((currRight - currLeft) >> 1);
            return sumUtil(currLeft, mid, treeIdx * 2 + 1) +
                sumUtil(mid + 1, currRight, treeIdx * 2 + 2);
        }
    }

    function update(idx, val) {
        var diff = val - nums[idx];
        nums[idx] = val;
        updateUtil(0, nums.length - 1, 0);

        function updateUtil(left, right, treeIdx) {
            if (idx >= left && idx <= right) {
                tree[treeIdx] += diff;
                if (left === right) return;
                var mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);
                updateUtil(left, mid, treeIdx * 2 + 1);
                updateUtil(mid + 1, right, treeIdx * 2 + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    function build(left, right, idx) {
        if (left > right) return;
        var mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);
        var sum = left === right ? nums[left] :
            build(left, mid, idx * 2 + 1) + build(mid + 1, right, idx * 2 + 2);

        tree[idx] = sum;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

incase you don't want to update the sum array you can precompute a sum array as

```
sum[i] = sum[i-1] + element[i]
// now the sum of l to r can be calculated as
desired_sum = sum[r] - sum[l-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I understand no matter what you do the best optimization you can get is O(n^2). That is because you have to traverse the first array once times the range to get the sum value. Unless you are planning on skipping some array elements the best you can go for is O(n^2)